# Querying Aurora via Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Function queries data from an Aurora database. Aurora database is the MySQL engine therefore, I'm querying it with a MySQL NPM module. If there is something better, I'm all ears.

The calling function has a try-catch block to manage exceptions. This function just connects to Aurora, submits a query, and displays the results to the console.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

function aurora_query_decorator(host, user, password, port, database) {
    const esb_db_connectionstring = {
        "host" : host,
        "user" : user,
        "password" : password,
        "port" : port,
        "database" : database,
        "connectTimeout" : 5000
    };
    console.log('Connection String: ', esb_db_connectionstring);

    console.log("Attempting to connect to Aurora...");
    const esb_db = mysql.createConnection(esb_db_connectionstring);

    esb_db.connect( (error) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        const esb_db_query_sql = "select * from things";
        console.log('Query: ', esb_db_query_sql);

        console.log("Attempting to query Aurora...");
        esb_db_query = esb_db.query(esb_db_query_sql);

        esb_db_query.on('error', error => { throw error } );

        esb_db_query.on('fields', data => { console.log(data) } );

        esb_db_query.on('end', () => { esb_db.end() } );
    });

    return;
}
```

Looking for general feedback. All constructive feedback welcome.

Ultimately, I'll be querying Aurora from Lambda functions. Does it make sense to try to [pool connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)?